# Priority queue with Pointers and Comparator C++

Tags: c++, pointers, priority-queue, comparator

I just started to learn C++, Half of the time I don't know what am I doing, spend hours and hours searching on Google and blindly put codes inside my project, this might be a basic question, but I just can't seems to get it right.

**This is the requirement** of my assignment, I need to have these:

**in the Edge class:**

```
public:
bool operator()(Edge*, Edge*)
```

**in the Graph class:**

```
private:
priority_queue<Edge*, vector<Edge*>, Edge> edges
```

**I have problem declaring the priority_queue. Details:**

If I directly use these, the edge class will give me an error of "must have an argument of class", I understand that I can't overload two pointers into the bool operator, so **this is what I have tried:**

**in the Edge.cpp:**

```
#include "Edge.h"
using namespace std;

Edge::Edge(Vertex* s, Vertex* d, double w)
{
    source = s;
    destination = d;
    weight = w;
}

double Edge::getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}

struct CompareWeight : public std::binary_function<Edge*, Edge*, bool>
{
    bool operator()(Edge* e1,Edge* e2)
    {
        double w1 = e1->getWeight();
        double w2 = e2->getWeight();

        if(w1>w2){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

^ I am not even sure about putting struct inside the class is correct or not, Plus in this cause I don't know what to put inside my Edge.h file.

**in the Edge.h:**

```
#include "Vertex.h"
class Edge
{
    public:
        Edge(Vertex*, Vertex*, double);
        double getWeight();
        friend struct CompareWeight; // ??? does not seems right
    private:
        Vertex* source;
        Vertex* destination;
        double weight;
}
```

As for the Graph class is where the real problem is, I can't even get pass declaring the priority queue without getting an error.

**in the Graph.h**

```
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Edge.h"
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class Graph
{
    public:
        ...

    private:
        priority_queue<Edge*, vector<Edge*>, Edge> edges
        // This give pointer error: no match for call to '(Edge) (Edge*&, Edge*&)'
}
```

second attempt:

```
// same as above
private:
    priority_queue<Edge*, vector<Edge*>, CompareWeight> edges
    // This give error: 'CompareWeight' not declared in this scope
```

I don't know why for the first error, but the second error I understood it clearly, but I don't know how to fix it, should I put something in front of CompareWeight? I tried many things, nothing work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! otherwise I would probably just fail this course.
First time asking in stackoverflow, if I did anything wrong please tell me.

Comment: Your first attempt looks like it could work. You should post a minimal example that reproduces the problem, and provide the error message too.

Comment: How comes you just started C++, and yet have such an awful lot of things to use at once ? OT: keep your CompareWeight struct, drop the inheritance (this uses static polymorphism). Then address the "not declared in this scope" problem by posting a broader view of your code (it's a structural problem).

Comment: I am not too sure what should I post, should I post what I have include? because those are the very things cause the problem and nothing else is really related? and what does "drop the inheritance" mean, which code you referring to?

Comment: By the way, the access specifier keywords (public: private: etc) should be lower case.

Comment: You tried one thing. You say it didn't work, then you tried other random things. Better to understand why the first one didn't work. So, post a minimal, self-contained example based on the first attempt, together with the error it produces. Because it looks almost OK.

Comment: I added in a lot more code but I feel they are unrelated. it's not a self-contained example tho.. because there's around 14 files linked together I don't know how to just take part of it out. I'm very noob at this thing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your requirement of implementing `bool operator()(Edge*, Edge*)` as a regular *member* of class `Edge` is possible, but rarely is it done that way.

Comparators for standard library algorithms come in the following idiomatic flavors, **all** of which must provide a strict weak ordering of the contained objects within the sequence being worked over:

1. Stand-alone functor class
2. Stand-alone `operator <` overload
3. Object-class member `operator <` overload.
4. Stand-alone function
5. Static class function
6. Static class functor class
7. A few others...

The fifth (5) on this list is the closest thing that looks like what they instruction was *trying* to do, but it is *never* implemented as `operator()`. It is *possible* to do (1) as a member of `Edge`, but to do so the `Edge` type must support *default construction*. I'll explain in a minute how this can be done. Of the options listed above, the best candidates for performance (likeliness of inlining) and implementation ease are (1) and (6) for this specific case. If your queue held actual `Edge` *objects* rather than `Edge` *pointers* (3) would be a natural fit as well as offer decent performance.

The point of a comparator for ordered containers and container adapters like a priority queue is to compare two items that are held within in compliance with a *strict weak ordering*. If you don't know what that is, [see this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). In implementation, it comes down to this: if, *and only if* `x < y` return **true**, otherwise return **false**. That means the following must be enforced:

- `x < x` always returns **false**
- if `x < y` returns **true**, then `y < x` **must** return **false**
- if both `x < y` and `y < x` return false, then `x` is *equivalent* to `y`

It is a common mistake to accidentally code one's comparator to not abide by these rules. Guard against that.

Anyway, I digress. One way of doing this *correctly* given your class definitions and using (1) from the list above is:

**Class Edge**

```
class Edge
{
public:
    Edge(Vertex* src, Vertex* dst, double w)
        : source(src), destination(dst), weight(w)
    {
    };

    // note: const-ness
    double getWeight() const { return weight; }

    Vertex const* getSource() const { return source; }
    Vertex* getSource() { return source; }

    Vertex const* getDestination() const { return destination; }
    Vertex* getDestination() { return destination; }

private:
    Vertex* source;
    Vertex* destination;
    double weight;
};
```

**Class CmpEdgePtrs**

```
struct CmpEdgePtrs
{
    bool operator()(const Edge* lhs, const Edge* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->getWeight() < rhs->getWeight();
    }
};
```

**Class Graph**

```
class Graph
{
    // rest of class stuff

private:
    priority_queue<Edge*, vector<Edge*>, CmpEdgePtrs> edges;
};
```

Honestly, this is screaming for usage of shared smart pointers, but I leave that to you. The code above stands a very strong chance of inlining the comparator throughout the usage locations within the standard library algorithms that implement the priority queue logic, and as such performance will stand a strong chance of being optimal given your constraints of a container of pointers.

---

**Fulfilling Assigned Requirements**

This *can* be done entirely within class `Edge`, since it is after all just a class type. The third type passed as the template parameter for the priority queue adapter is something that exposes `bool operator()`, and there is nothing stopping you from just making an instance of `Edge` do that for you. It is odd, but it will none-the-less work with a couple modifications:

First, move the `bool operator()(const Edge*, const Edge*) const` to the `Edge` class, declared as public. Second, provide a default constructor for `Edge`, since it will be needed by the internal algorithms of the priority queue when creating the functor to perform the comparisons.

```
class Edge
{
public:
    // regular parameterized construction
    Edge(Vertex* src, Vertex* dst, double w)
        : source(src), destination(dst), weight(w)
    {
    };

    // ADDED: allows parameterless initialization
    Edge() 
        : source(), designation(), weight() 
    {}

    // note: const-ness
    double getWeight() const { return weight; }

    Vertex const* getSource() const { return source; }
    Vertex* getSource() { return source; }

    Vertex const* getDestination() const { return destination; }
    Vertex* getDestination() { return destination; }

    // ADDED: used when an instance of `Edge` is used as comparator functor
    bool operator ()(const Edge* lhs, const Edge* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->weight < rhs->weight;
    }

private:
    Vertex* source;
    Vertex* destination;
    double weight;
};


class Graph
{
    // rest of class stuff

private:
    // NOTE: uses Edge-type as the functor type that will
    //  deliver the comparison of Edge pointers.
    priority_queue<Edge*, vector<Edge*>, Edge> edges;
};
```

This is *highly unusual*, but has the benefit of allowing the functor direct access to the member variables of `Edge` objects being compared rather than going through public getters and setters or having to friend a comparator. It has a downside though. There is nothing stopping someone *besides* the container adapter from constructing `Edge` objects without specifying source, destination, and weight.

In short, there is little benefit to doing it like this, and potential problems in improper usage of the code required to make this work, and for that, I would recommend the first option instead.

Best of luck

Comment: WOW. I don't know what to say , you are *Awesome* <3<3<3! Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! Solution both works perfectly, I go with the 2nd at the end because I am really not sure about making a new class, if it's against the rule. I have been struggling at this for so long, stressed out because without the vector edge, I can't store any data and simply can't do most of the required calculations, which mean failing the course. You are my super super hero now <3!

Comment: Thank you!!! This answer is way too underrated!!! Given the question being pretty well-framed and somewhat common (i think,) AND with such a great answer, it's a pity that not more people are seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is called a forward declaration. In Edge.h, you are allowed to write just `class Vertex;` on a line by itself. After this line, C++ knows that there is such a class, and that `Vertex *` therefore is a pointer (and not an the first half of a multiplication).

[edit]
This forward declaration replaces `#include "Vertex.h"` inside Edge.h.

Comment: Where in Edge.h should I put `class Vertex;`? I put it under public, it gives `error: declaration of 'struct Edge::Vertex'` and `error: changes meaning of 'Vertex' from 'class Vertex'`

Comment: Well, not _inside_ class Edge, obviously. Inside class Edge you only define the members of Edge. And you do have to declare Vertex before using `Vertex*`, so _after_ class Edge is not an option either. That just leaves one option, _before_ class Edge. You could have figured that out yourself.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to C++, I've tired that as well, it just simply didn't change anything. error still the same , still there. Note that the error I'm getting is from Graph.h , where I tried to declare the Priority queue

Comment: Sorry, should have been more explicit. Edited