# Calling virtual compare for priority in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, priority-queue

I am trying to create an abstract class for representing data and have a compare function setup. My priority queue stores pointers to these abstract data classes.

The abstract data class implements the () operator to do the initial comparison, but then calls a virtual compare function to do custom comparisons.

Here is the code:

```
class AbsData {

public:
    AbsData() {
        order = 0;
    }

    AbsData(int order) {
        this->order = order;
    }

    virtual ~AbsData() {}

    bool operator()(const AbsData* p1, const AbsData* p2) const {
        if (p1 && !p2)
            return false;

        if (!p1 && p2)
            return true;

        if (!p1 && !p2)
            return true;

        return this->compare(p1, p2);
    }

    virtual bool compare(const AbsData *p1, const AbsData *p2) const {
        return p1->getOrder() > p2->getOrder();
    }

    int getOrder() const
    {
        return order;
    }

private:
    int order;

};
```

I then use this abstract data class to represent other types of data:

```
class FFTData : public AbsData {

public:
    FFTData(ImageStitching::FFTWImageTile * tile, int order) : AbsData(order)
    {
        this->tile = tile;
    }

    ImageStitching::FFTWImageTile * getTile() const {
        return this->tile;
    }


    // Should override the virtual compare
    bool compare(const AbsData *p1, const AbsData *p2) const {
        return p1->getOrder() < p2->getOrder();
    }

private:
    ImageStitching::FFTWImageTile * tile;
};
```

I define my priority queue like this:

```
std::priority_queue<AbsData *, std::vector<AbsData *>, AbsData> queue;
```

What am I missing from this setup? It will not call the FFTData's `compare` function.

NOTE: this is just testing the functionality, so although at this time the FFTData compare function essentially should inverse the ordering of non NULL AbsData pointers, eventually it will add more functionality.

Comment: check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997104/priority-queue-with-pointers-and-comparator-c

Comment: The AbsData operator is being called by the std lib priority_queue, so the comparison is being done correctly for the pointers. It is just not calling the child's compare function... Only sticking to the AbsData compare function.

Comment: When you create your FFTData objects, how are you doing so?

Comment: @ChaseHenslee, doesn't matter. OP doesn't call right overload.

Comment: TIL how the function operator works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `return this->compare(p1, p2);` from the instance of your AbsData comparator. It is not of the derived class!

To fix the problem, call compare on one of the pointers passed to it. Better yet, do not mix comparator and data. Create an independent comparator class.

You have another improvment pending in your code - do away with raw pointers, switch to the smart ones.

Comment: I will see what I can do with smart pointers. I'm more familiar with C and do not have much experience in C++. I read about them and they seem like a nice way to manage the memory and worry less about leaks. Thanks for the suggestion.